# .fancybox is not being recognised as a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I've gone through the other solutions to this question and none seem to work. I still think there is a problem with the scripts. Here is my :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimal-ui" />

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

    <!-- BS -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- Fancybox -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src-"fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {      
            if(location.hash) {
                $(location.hash).click();
            }
            $(".iframe").fancybox();
        });
    </script>

</head>
```

And body:

```
<a class="iframe" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/151002965">
    <img src="https://vimeo.com/151002965">
</a>
```

Comment: The order of scripts looks fine. Have you checked to make sure the paths to the fancybox JS files are ok?

Comment: Yes all 3 load fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it have some type mistake

```
<script type="text/javascript" src-"fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

please correct it as,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

try once again it may help you

Comment: Well spotted, took me a while to notice the `-` and `=` had changed

Comment: Didn't notice the "-", changed that but still the same error. I also get an error in the fancybox JS: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590565/why-isnt-my-fancybox-function-working

Comment: see that your problem seems like same,

Comment: Cheers mate. That is stupid though, why did they make JQuery incompatible with one of it's most popular plugins?