# TypeError: f.browser is undefined fancybox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I am facing error in my app/assets/javascripts/jquery/jquery.fancybox.pack.js file at this line:

```
5: (f.browser.msie?' allowtransparency="true"':"")+"></iframe>",error:'<p class="fancybox-error">The requested content cannot be loaded.<br/>
```

At top of this file the version is mentioned as:

```
/*! fancyBox v2.1.0 fancyapps.com | fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license */
```

I am using jquery-rails-3.1.4 and jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5 versions. 
Please help how can I get out of this error.

Comment: You might be facing this scenario http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987

Answer (score 0):

Import fancybox script like that,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

Please see that [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789460/fancybox-is-not-being-recognised-as-a-function/34789687#34789687) it may help you